# How to filter json array returned from a JSON column in a PostgreSQL table?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to get the reduced (filtered?) JSON array from a table

Consider the following example

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."test_data" (
    "id" uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    "a_field" jsonb NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

INSERT INTO test_data (a_field) VALUES 
('[ {"id": 1, "value": 100}, {"id": 2, "value": 200}, {"id": 2, "value": 50} ]');
```

The data structure stored in the `test_data.a_field` field is an array of `{ id: number, value: number }` objects.

Given the example above, I need to get the data for a specific `id` of the object, so instead of this

```
[ {"id": 1, "value": 100}, {"id": 2, "value": 200}, {"id": 2, "value": 50} ]
```

I could get this?

```
[ {"id": 2, "value": 200}, {"id": 2, "value": 50} ]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_array_elements()` and `jsonb_agg()` functions consecutively :

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(js) as a_field_new
  FROM
  (
   SELECT jsonb_array_elements(a_field) as js
     FROM test_data
  ) q
 WHERE js->> 'id' = '2'
```

OR without subquery :

```
SELECT jsonb_agg(value) as a_field_new 
  FROM test_data
 CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(a_field)
 WHERE value->> 'id' = '2'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=98589111b1e864ae1e8628304e6e8fec)</kbd>